# Office Add-in DialogAPI 1.2 Close method terminates Web App and stops Visual Studio debugging

Tags: office-js, office-addins, blazor-webassembly

My Office Add-in is launched in Visual Studio 2022 for debugging in the following manner:

[image]

The Office Add-in implements a fall-back authentication mechanism using Office dialog API.

But when I close the dialog in the callback method, it closes **both** the dialog window launched by Office dialog API **and** the browser window of the Web Application (BlazorApp.Server) that was launched by Visual Studio debugging session.

```
export let loginDialog;

export function LoginFallbackInterop() {

    let url = "/azureadauth/login";
    let fullUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '') + url;

    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(fullUrl,
        { height: 60, width: 30 }, function (result) {
            
            loginDialog = result.value;            
            
            loginDialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
        });
}

export function processMessage(arg) {

    let message = JSON.parse(arg.message);

     loginDialog.close();

}
```

I have tried setting Visual Studio debugger to launch Web Application in Google Chrome browser, while Excel loads the Web Application in Task Pane and Office Dialog in Microsoft Edge browser, but when dialog close method is called, it also terminates Web Application in Google Chrome browser and thereby terminates my debugging session.

Using latest build of Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise Version 2206 (Build 15330.20230)

Comment: I am having similar issue. Found any solution for same ??

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is as follows:

A Blazor WASM Hosted application contains a `launchSettings.json` file each for Blazor Client and Blazor Server project.

Within the `launchSettings.json` file for Blazor Server project set `launchBrowser` to `false` i.e.

```
  "profiles": {
  "BlazorApp.Server": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "launchBrowser": false,
    "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7288;http://localhost:5176",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  }
```

And as before, ensure you are starting up only Excel sideloader project and Blazor Server project

[image]